# How can I limit the rows to one in database?

Tags: xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.forms

[I have a table named profit model:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZZfV.png)

I would like to active different profitmodel, and the data in table will be updated.

Now I am using UpdateAsync, but it doesn't work... How can I achieve this?

```
async void Active_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var profitmodel = (sender as Button).CommandParameter as ProfitModel;

        await conn.CreateTableAsync<ProfitModelInUsed>();

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(product.ProductName);

        var profitmodelInUsed = new ProfitModelInUsed
        {
            ProfitModel_ID = profitmodel.ProfitModel_ID,
            ProfitModel_Name = profitmodel.ProfitModel_Name,
            ExchangeRate = profitmodel.ExchangeRate,
            Profit = profitmodel.Profit
        };

        await conn.UpdateAsync(profitmodelInUsed);

        await DisplayAlert("This ProfitModel is Applied", profitmodelInUsed.ProfitModel_Name, "OK");
    }
```

And I don't want to have more than one rows in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a `PrimaryKey` to your `ProfitModel_ID` property within your `ProfitModelInUsed` model:

```
public class ProfitModelInUsed
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ProfitModel_ID { get; set; }
    // ~~~ other properties
}
```

And set the `ProfitModel_ID` property using a `const`:

```
profitmodelInUsed.ProfitModel_ID = "InUseProfitModel"
await conn.UpdateAsync(profitmodelInUsed);
```

Retrive it via:

```
var profitmodelinuse = conn.FindAsync<ProfitModelInUsed>("InUseProfitModel");
```

Comment: Thanks Bro !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Your advice is helpful!!!!!!!!!!